# Extracting files and directories from a provided list into separate lists

Tags: c#, file-system

This code gets a list of all files and directories from a specific location. Thes code below works.

```
List<string> FullList = new List<string>(LoadFiles("patch.txt"));
List<string> ShortCatalogList = new List<string>();
List<string> ShortFileList = new List<string>();


            for (int i = 0; i < FullList.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (System.IO.Path.HasExtension(FullList[i]))
                    {
                    ShortFileList.Add(FullList[i]);
                    }


                    if (!System.IO.Path.HasExtension(FullList[i]))
                    {
                        ShortCatalogList.Add(FullList[i]);

                    if (Directory.GetFiles(FullList[i]).Length > 0)
                        {                           
                            string[] subFile = Directory.GetFiles(FullList[i]);
                                for (int io = 0; io < subFile.Length; io++)
                                    {
                                        ShortFileList.Add(subFile[io]);
                                    }
                        }

                    if (Directory.GetDirectories(FullList[i]).Length > 0)
                     {
                            string[] subFolder = Directory.GetDirectories(FullList[i]);

                            for (int io = 0; io < subFolder.Length; io++)
                            {
                                FullList.Add(subFolder[io]);
                            }                   
                   }
                  }
                 }
```

I know that I need to protect from permission problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most is said about this code in the other answer, but there is a simplification which can be used to beautify this code a lot.

The `Directory` class has two methods which returns `IEnumerable<string>` namely [`EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`EnumerateDirectories()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The results of the calls to this methods can be used to call `AddRange()` on the `ShortFileList` and `FullList`.

Like so

```
List<string> fullList = new List<string>(LoadFiles("patch.txt"));
List<string> shortCatalogList = new List<string>();
List<string> shortFileList = new List<string>();


for (int i = 0; i < fullList.Count; i++)
{

    if (System.IO.Path.HasExtension(fullList[i]))
    {
        shortFileList.Add(fullList[i]);
        continue;
    }

    shortCatalogList.Add(fullList[i]);

    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(fullList[i]);
    shortFileList.AddRange(files);

    var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(fullList[i]);
    fullList.AddRange(directories);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code's indentation is pretty terrible. Keeping a good indentation is *the* key to keep maintainable code. With any good IDE, you can auto-format your code!

Also, considering the naming conventions, your variables should be `camelCased`, not `PascalCased`. So `FullList -> fullList`. And `subFile` holds multiple files, so you should pluralize it! `subFile -> subFiles`

You should import the `System.IO` instead of typing `System.IO.Path.HasExtension` all the time.

You do this using `using System.IO;` (if you didn't know already).

Instead of having :

```
if (System.IO.Path.HasExtension(FullList[i]))
{ }
if (!System.IO.Path.HasExtension(FullList[i]))
{ }
```

You should use the `else` statement :

```
if (System.IO.Path.HasExtension(FullList[i]))
{ }
else
{ }
```

As @Heslacher pointed out, you should use the `AddRange` method, it does the same thing as :

```
for (int io = 0; io < subFile.Length; io++)
{
    ShortFileList.Add(subFile[io]);
}
```

So well, that's less code! :)

You shouldn't call `Directory.GetFiles(FullList[i])` twice. It's the most costly operation in your code, so you should call it only once! Same thing for `Directory.GetDirectories(FullList[i])`.

Instead of typing `fullList[i]` all the time, you should create a variable to hold it! Not that accessing an array is that expansive, but well, it'll help for readability.

So, let's check the final code :

```
List<string> fullList = new List<string>(LoadFiles("patch.txt"));
List<string> shortCatalogList = new List<string>();
List<string> shortFileList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < fullList.Count; i++)
{
    string path = fullList[i];
    if (Path.HasExtension(path))
    {
        shortFileList.Add(path);
    }
    else
    {
        shortCatalogList.Add(path);
        string[] subFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        string[] subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

        if (subFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            shortFileList.AddRange(subFiles);
        }
        if (subFolders.Length > 0)
        {
            fullList.AddRange(subFolders);
        }
    }
}
```